# configure nginx with magento1.9 404 not found error Ubuntu 16.04 LEMP

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, magento-1.9

Im trying to install magento 1.9 with Ubuntu LEMP and my nginx config is as:

After configuring the Virtual host i get 404 not found error in the console.

Where am i wrong as im new to Nginx config

My website root is:

**/var/www/html/mage19.com**

**\etc\nginx\sites-available\mage19.com**

```
server {
    listen 80;

    ## SSL directives might go here
    ## see http://www.howtoforge.com/how_to_set_up_ssl_vhosts_under_nginx_plus_sni_support_ubuntu_11.04_debian_squeeze
    ## if you want to enable SSL for this vhost

    server_name mage19.com *.mage19.com;
    root /var/www/html/mage19.com/;

    ## rewrites example.com to www.example.com
    if ($http_host != "mage19.com") {
        rewrite ^ $scheme://mage19.com$request_uri permanent;
    }

    location / {
        index index.html index.php; ## Allow a static html file to be shown first
        try_files $uri $uri/ @handler; ## If missing pass the URI to Magento's front handler
        expires 30d; ## Assume all files are cachable
    }

    ## These locations would be hidden by .htaccess normally
    location /app/                { deny all; }
    location /includes/           { deny all; }
    location /lib/                { deny all; }
    location /media/downloadable/ { deny all; }
    location /pkginfo/            { deny all; }
    location /report/config.xml   { deny all; }
    location /var/                { deny all; }

    location /var/export/ { ## Allow admins only to view export folder
        auth_basic           "Restricted"; ## Message shown in login window
        auth_basic_user_file /var/www/html/www/mage19.com/.htpasswd; ## See /etc/nginx/htpassword
        autoindex            on;
    }

    ## Disable .htaccess and other hidden files
    location ~ /. {
        deny all;
    }

    location @handler { ## Magento uses a common front handler
        rewrite / /index.php;
    }

    location ~ .php/ { ## Forward paths like /js/index.php/x.js to relevant handler
        rewrite ^(.*.php)/ $1 last;
    }

    location ~ .php$ { ## Execute PHP scripts
        if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite / /index.php last; } ## Catch 404s that try_files miss

        expires        off; ## Do not cache dynamic content
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param  MAGE_RUN_CODE default; ## Store code is defined in administration &gt; Configuration &gt; Manage Stores
        fastcgi_param  MAGE_RUN_TYPE store;
        include        fastcgi_params; ## See /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params
    }
}
```

ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/mage19.com /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/mage19.com

My magentos **\var\www\html\mage19.com\app\etc\local.xml** is :

```
<config>
<global>
    <install>
        <date><![CDATA[Wed, 26 Oct 2016 05:50:20 +0000]]></date>
    </install>
    <crypt>
        <key><![CDATA[007ca2f244638754af2b525998fdf429]]></key>
    </crypt>
    <disable_local_modules>false</disable_local_modules>
    <resources>
        <db>
            <table_prefix><![CDATA[]]></table_prefix>
        </db>
        <default_setup>
            <connection>
                <host><![CDATA[localhost]]></host>
                <username><![CDATA[root]]></username>
                <password><![CDATA[passowrd]]></password>
                <dbname><![CDATA[magento19]]></dbname>
                <initStatements><![CDATA[SET NAMES utf8]]></initStatements>
                <model><![CDATA[mysql4]]></model>
                <type><![CDATA[pdo_mysql]]></type>
                <pdoType><![CDATA[]]></pdoType>
                <active>1</active>
            </connection>
        </default_setup>
    </resources>
    <session_save><![CDATA[files]]></session_save>
</global>
<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <frontName><![CDATA[admin]]></frontName>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
</config>
```

Comment: Did you using default config setting?

Comment: yes tried with default nginx config also and created a virtual host mage19 as above.. for both same error...no logs as well

Comment: I think that you should try to clean config file. I'm not sure some of them are use or not.

Comment: what does clean config file mean?  do u mean to remove them from etc/ngninx/sites-available or remove the symlink of them?

Comment: What I meant is remove unnecessary configuration setting

Comment: i have oly default nginx and my newly created config and i removed mine and tried with default..i get same error, cleared cache too

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128268/discussion-between-kelvin-kyaw-and-sachin-s).